# Why is this Todo app build failing in Jenkins when deploying on AWS Linux using Docker file in WSL2?

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

So I was trying to deploy a simple CD pipeline using docker by ssh’ing into my AWS Linux EC2 instance in the WSL2 terminal. The job is failing every time returning the following error:

> Started by user Navdeep Singh Running as SYSTEM Building on the
> built-in node in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/todo-dev
> [todo-dev] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6737039323529850559.sh + cd
> /home/ubuntu/project/django-todo /tmp/jenkins6737039323529850559.sh:
> 2: **cd: can’t cd to /home/ubuntu/project/django-todo** Build step
> ‘Execute shell’ marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

[image: Job Config]

DockerFile contents:

> FROM python:3 RUN pip install django==3.2
>
> COPY . .
>
> RUN python manage.py migrate
>
> CMD [“python”,“manage.py”,“runserver”,“0.0.0.0:8000”]

Answer (score 1):

I was also doing the same, just check that you haven't used snap to download docker. If yes, then uninstall the docker and install it using apt.

Answer (score 0):

Everything goes fine. This error `cd: can’t cd to /home/ubuntu/project/django-todo Build step ‘Execute shell’ marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE` is not an actual.

Your agent Node is not online.

To fix the problem, find commands on your jenkins web page after an agent setup. You need to run those commands from your terminal. See the screenshot for more details.

[image]

Make sure that your jenkins public IP and node agent public IP are the same. If an error occurs, you need to run some commands on the terminal. This is not a real error.

Answer (score 0):

this issue follow this step which i give you

For Agent--->

change your ip here(44.203.138.174:8080) to your EC2 ip

1.curl -sO http://44.203.138.174:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar
2.java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://44.203.138.174:8080/manage/computer/todo%2Dagent/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret beb62de0f81bfd06e4cd81d1b896d85d38f82b87b21ef8baef3389e651c9f72c -workDir "/home/ubuntu"

For JOb --->

1. sudo vi  /etc/sudoers
2. then add this command below root access in sudoers file
   jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

3.then goto the ubuntu directory using cd .. then run this codes
grep ^ubuntu /etc/group
id jenkins
sudo adduser jenkins ubuntu
grep ^ubuntu /etc/group

4.restart the jenkins relogin
sudo systemctl stop jenkins

then you good to go

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and resolve with the following configuration in the Execute shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker build -t todo-img4 -f /root/project/django-todo/Dockerfile /root/project/django-todo
sudo docker run -d -it -p 8001:8001 todo-img4
```

Answer (score 0):

Add These Steps to your executing script

```
echo "Current User: $(whoami)"
echo "Current Directory: $(pwd)"
ls -l
cd /home/ubuntu/Projects/django-todo
sudo docker build . -t todo-dev
sudo docker run -d -p 8001:8001 todo-dev
```